# UIBarButtonItem does not show disabled state titleTextAttributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to set the disabled `textAttributes` on a `UIBarButtonItem` in a `UIToolbar`.

I create my item like so:

```
NSDictionary *enabledAttrs  =  @{ NSFontAttributeName               : font,
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName    : color };

NSDictionary *disabledAttrs =  @{ NSFontAttributeName               : font,
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName    : [UIColor grayColor] };

[item setTitleTextAttributes:enabledAttrs forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[item setTitleTextAttributes:disabledAttrs forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

However, when i set `item.enabled = NO`, the button is disabled (it does not fire its action) but it does not honor its `titleTextAttributes` -- it still appears in the normal state. Why?

Comment: are u sure about the properties you are setting? do you want to change the background color or the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Create UIButton and wrap with UIBarbutton,I think it should be work.

```
UIButton *uiButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[uiButton setTitleColor: color1 forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[uiButton setTitleColor: color2 forState: UIControlStateDisabled];

UIBarButtonItem *uiBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:uiButton];
```